# Run Internet Explorer with disabled cookies in selenium

Tags: selenium

the problem is that I can't figure out how to run IE with disabled cookies. I can't disable cookies in IE beforehand too, as I need to have two separate test suites - one running for IE with disabled cookies, and another for IE with enabled cookies. For Firefox and Chrome it's easy enough - we create separate profiles for each mode of browsers. Could anyone suggest how to do that?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Internet explorer, You need to clear temporary files as well to run your tests cookie free.
Unfortunately selenium does not have inbuilt support for that. What you can do as work around is,

In IE, go to

> Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced

In the settings window, scroll down to see `"Security"` category, From there you check,

> Empty Temporary Internet Files Folder when browser is closed option.

Now if you close the browser, and open it the instance will be cookie free.